# Inline 3 images using the whole width of the paper

Tags: graphics, width

So,

I've tried using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431756/image-matrix-using-the-whole-line-width) method but I keep having this:

[image]

I would like my three images to use the whole width (or like 90% of it) of the paper and not only the `\textwidth`

Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand you correnctly, you want to evenly let the images overflow into the left and right margin. Is that correct? If so, the `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` pachage might be useful (See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154766/134144)

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis I've found out how to do that.

Before the `\begin{document}` use

```
\usepackage{changepage}
\newlength{\offsetpage}
\setlength{\offsetpage}{3.0cm}
\newenvironment{widepage}{\begin{adjustwidth}{-\offsetpage}{-\offsetpage}%
    \addtolength{\textwidth}{2\offsetpage}}%
{\end{adjustwidth}}
```

where `3.0cm` is the amount of space you want to overflow from the margins.

Then you simply use it as

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{widepage}
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PMF_57.eps}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image1}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PMF_570.eps}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image2}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PMF_57000.eps}
  \caption{A really Awesome Image}\label{fig:awesome_image3}
\endminipage
\end{widepage}
\end{figure}
```